# Unmet Dependencies with Audacity on Xubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, xubuntu, dependencies

My machine is running Xubuntu Xenial.
I've recently installed Audacity from the software centre. It installed and worked fine. However, at the next update of the machine I got unmet dependencies issues.

I can't add/remove anything. My understanding is that I need to have libqtcore version: 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2 installed but APT is refusing to install it. Then it seems that something wicked is happening to the file 'Trolltech.conf' but I'm not sure what.

What's happened and how can I fix it?

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies.
    libqt4-declarative : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
    libqt4-network : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
    libqt4-script : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
    libqt4-sql : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
    libqt4-sql-mysql : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
    libqt4-xml : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
    libqt4-xmlpatterns : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
    libqtdbus4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
    libqtgui4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
    libsuil-0-0 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not going to be installed
    qdbus : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
    qt-at-spi : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8~) but it is not going to be installed

    paul@ubuntusonar:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
    [sudo] password for paul:
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done 
    Correcting dependencies... Done
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
    linux-headers-4.4.0-59 linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-63 linux-headers-4.4.0-63-generic linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic linux-image-4.4.0-63-generic
    linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-63-generic
    Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
    The following additional packages will be installed:
     libqtcore4
    The following NEW packages will be installed
     libqtcore4
    0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 30 not to upgrade.
    14 not fully installed or removed.
    Need to get 0 B/1,552 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 5,092 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    (Reading database ... 265038 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libqtcore4:amd64 (4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) ...
    dpkg: error processing archive 
      /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
    trying to overwrite shared '/etc/xdg/Trolltech.conf', which is different from other instances of package libqtcore4:amd64
    dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
      /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Make a backup in your home folder of the file `/etc/xdg/Trolltech.conf`. Then remove it using: `sudo rm /etc/xdg/Trolltech.conf`. Then, use: `sudo apt-get autoremove`, `sudo apt-get autoclean`,  `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Finally, try to install the requiered packages again.

Comment: Wicked thank you for such a fast response. I cant get to the machine until weekend but will let you all know what happens. Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as GTRONICK says, but also be sure to purge audacity `sudo apt purge audacity` before you `sudo apt upgrade` and reinstall via the commandline.
`sudo apt install audacity`.

If problems persist, you may want to consider an alternative to audacity. Audour and Ocenaudio are decent.

Comment: Wicked thank you for such a fast response. I cant get to the machine until weekend but will let you all know what happens. Paul

Comment: @paulfurze You're welcome!

Comment: @GTRONIK
This worked guys. Had to run..
'sudo apt-get install -f'
..at the end but it then went merrily along and sorted itself. 

Many thanks.